# Top-Align Rotated Text in Cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

I have cells in a `tabular` environment that have the text rotate 90 degrees. I am unclear as to how to have the text be 'top' aligned, i.e., right justified given the rotate text. Below is what is currently being produced and the TeX generating it. What I would want to see is all the text in the cells even along the top of the cell, ragged along the bottom.

[image]

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.32in}}

% other irrelevant preamble code

\begin{center}
{\tabcolsep=0pt\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ | R | R | R | R | R | R | R | R | R | R | }
\multicolumn{10}{c}{\HUGE January}\bigskip\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Wednesday, January 1~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Thursday, January 2~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Friday, January 3~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Saturday, January 4~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Sunday, January 5~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Monday, January 6~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Tuesday, January 7~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Wednesday, January 8~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Thursday, January 9~~} & \rotatebox{90} {~~~~~~~~Friday, January 10~~} \\    \hline

\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the packages `rotating` and `makecell`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.32in}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove space between tabular columns
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% Stretch rows vertically
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Wednesday, January 22}
\begin{tabular}{ | *{10}{C |} }
\multicolumn{10}{c}{\Huge January} \bigskip\\
    \hline
\rothead{\hfill Wednesday, January 1}  &
\rothead{\hfill Thursday, January 2}   &
\rothead{\hfill Friday, January 3}     &
\rothead{\hfill Saturday, January 4}   &
\rothead{\hfill Sunday, January 5}     &
\rothead{\hfill Monday, January 6}     &
\rothead{\hfill Tuesday, January 7}    &
\rothead{\hfill Wednesday, January 8}  &
\rothead{\hfill Thursday, January 9}   &
\rothead{\hfill Friday, January 10}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the rotational origin; in this case, `origin=r` seems to be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.32in}}

% other irrelevant preamble code

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove space between tabular columns
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% Stretch rows vertically
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{10}{R |} }
    \multicolumn{10}{c}{\Huge January} \bigskip\\
    \hline
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Wednesday, January 1~~}   & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Thursday, January 2~~}  & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Friday, January 3~~}    & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Saturday, January 4~~}  & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Sunday, January 5~~}    & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Monday, January 6~~}    & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Tuesday, January 7~~}   & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Wednesday, January 8~~} & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Thursday, January 9~~}  & 
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{~~~~~~~~Friday, January 10~~} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm...I copy and pasted your code, and it doesn't seem to have done anything with regards to the justification.